# User input strings into string vector and validating it

Tags: c++

So I'm creating a social media functionality program and I'm trying to store strings into a string vector by user input that act like tags. But before they are stored into the vector, they have to be validated by having a hashtag symbol before the string. If it is valid, the tag will be stored into the vector but if not valid it should repeat the user input prompt until it is valid.

Post.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"

//Regex
std::string posterRegex = "[A-Za-z0-9]{8,}";
std::string messageRegex = "[A-Za-z0-9]{1,}";

//Validates data against a user-defined string
bool validatePost(std::string regexStr, std::string data)
{
    return std::regex_match(data, std::regex(regexStr));
}

bool validateVector(const std::vector<std::string> &in)
{
    return std::none_of(std::begin(in), std::end(in), [](std::string 
    const &s)
    {
        return s.find("#") == std::string::npos;
    });
}

Post::Post()
{
}

Post::Post(std::string poster, std::string message, 
std::vector<std::string> tags, std::vector<User*> taggedUsers)
{
    setPoster(poster);
    setMessage(message);
    setTags(tags);
    setTaggedUsers(taggedUsers);
}


Post::~Post()
{
}

void Post::setPoster(std::string poster)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        bool bValid = validatePost(posterRegex, poster);
        if (bValid)
        {
            this->poster = poster;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Please enter a valid name!\n";
            std::cout << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Poster: ";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(512, '\n');
            std::cin >> poster;
        }
    }
}

void Post::setMessage(std::string message)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        bool bValid = validatePost(messageRegex, message);
        if (bValid)
        {
            this->message = message;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Please enter a valid message!\n";
            std::cout << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Message: ";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(512, '\n');
            std::cin >> message;
        }
    }
}

void Post::setTags(std::vector<std::string> tags)
{
    for (;;)
    {
                int i = 0;
        bool bValid = validateVector(tags);
        if (bValid)
        {
            this->tags = tags;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Please enter a valid tag(s)!\n";
            std::cout << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Tag(s): ";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(512, '\n');
            std::cin >> tags[i];
        }
    }
}

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream& osObject, const Post& coObject)
{
    osObject << coObject.poster << " - " << coObject.message;
    return osObject;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"

Post p;

int main()
{

    int i = 0;
    std::string poster;
    std::cout << "Poster: ";
    std::cin >> poster;
    p.setPoster(poster);
    std::cout << p.getPoster() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::string message;
    std::cout << "Message: ";
    std::cin >> message;
    p.setMessage(message);
    std::cout << p.getMessage() << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::vector<std::string> tags;
    std::cout << "Tags: ";
    std::cin >> tags[i];
    p.setTags(tags);
    std::cout << p.getTags().at(i) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    i++;
}
```

The program runs fine but when I reach the tags user input prompt, the program crashes and gives me a debug assertion failed error saying "expression: vector subscript out of range".

Comment: `std::cin >> tags[i];` and if there is no `tags[i]`? For example `tags` is empty? Sometimes as you gotta [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) against bugs like this or they'll walk all over ya.

Comment: *I reach the tags user input prompt, the program crashes* -- The program didn't actually crash.  You received an assertion which halted the program -- a crash implies that the program just suddenly stopped working because of a memory violation or similar error.  -- *and gives me a debug assertion failed error saying "expression: vector subscript out of range"* -- ok, so what in that error message is not understood?  Seems clear to me what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made only a minor logical error.

As user4581301  has already written in his comment:

When you define a vector, it initially has 0 elements. Meaning, even not element 0. So, after

```
std::vector<std::string> tags;
```

tags contains no elements, even not `tags[0]`. And if you try to write a value into `tags[i]`, with `int i = 0;` you create an out of bounds error. You write somewhere random in the memory.

How to avoid that?. You can create a vector with a given size in the constructor or you can use the vectors `resize` function or best, use the function intended for this use case: `push_back()`.

Change code to:

```
 std::vector<std::string> tags;
    std::cout << "Tags: ";
    std::string strTag;
    if (std::cin >> strTag)
        tags.push_back(strTag);
    p.setTags(tags);
    std::cout << p.getTags().at(i) << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    i++;
```

There are of course other possibilities. But this is easy to understand.